# return возвращает два значения

Tags: php, битрикс

правлю хлебные крошки в битриксе возникла проблема, в итоге почему то хб оборачивается два раза в

```
<div class="breadcrumbs" id="navigation" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
<div class="breadcrumbs" id="navigation" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">х-б</div></div>
```

Вот сам код шаблона

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();

if($arResult){
    \Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule("iblock");
    global $NextSectionID;
    $cnt = count($arResult);
    $lastindex = $cnt - 1;
    if(\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('aspro.next'))
    {
        global $arTheme;
        $bShowCatalogSubsections = ($arTheme["SHOW_BREADCRUMBS_CATALOG_SUBSECTIONS"]["VALUE"] == "Y");
    }

    for($index = 0; $index < $cnt; ++$index){
        $arSubSections = array();
        $arItem = $arResult[$index];
        $title = htmlspecialcharsex($arItem["TITLE"]);
        $bLast = $index == $lastindex;
        if($NextSectionID && $bShowCatalogSubsections){
            $arSubSections = CNext::getChainNeighbors($NextSectionID, $arItem['LINK']);
        }
        if($index){
            $strReturn .= '<span class="separator">-</span>';
        }
        if($arItem["LINK"] <> "" && $arItem['LINK'] != GetPagePath() && $arItem['LINK']."index.php" != GetPagePath() || $arSubSections){
            $strReturn .= '<div class="bx-breadcrumb-item'.($arSubSections ? ' drop' : '').($bLast ? ' cat_last' : '').'" id="bx_breadcrumb_'.$index.'" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">';
            if($arSubSections){
                if($index == ($cnt-1)):
                    $strReturn .= '<span class="number" itemprop="item">';
                else:
                    $strReturn .= '<a class="number" href="'.$arItem["LINK"].'" itemprop="item">';
                endif;
                $strReturn .=($arSubSections ? '<span itemprop="name">'.$title.'</span><b class="space"></b><span class="separator'.($bLast ? ' cat_last' : '').'"></span>' : '<span>'.$title.'</span>');
                $strReturn .= '<meta itemprop="position" content="'.($index + 1).'">';
                if($index == ($cnt-1)):
                    $strReturn .= '</span>';
                else:
                    $strReturn .= '</a>';
                endif;
                $strReturn .= '';
                    foreach($arSubSections as $arSubSection){
                        $strReturn .= '';
                    }
                $strReturn .= '';
            }
            else{
                $strReturn .= '<a href="'.$arItem["LINK"].'" title="'.$title.'" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">'.$title.'</span><meta itemprop="position" content="'.($index + 1).'"></a>';
            }
            $strReturn .= '</div>';
        }
        else{
            $strReturn .= '​<div class="bx-breadcrumb-item drop" id="bx_breadcrumb_4" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a href="" itemprop="item" ><span itemprop="name">'.$title.'<meta itemprop="position" content="'.($index + 1).'"></span></a></div>';
        }
    }

    return '<div class="breadcrumbs" id="navigation" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">'.$strReturn.'</div>';
}
else{
    return $strReturn;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в начало шаблона добавить

```
if(empty($arResult))
return "";

$strReturn = '';
```

Comment: к сожалению осталось так же

Comment: Тогда проверьте, что проблема именно в шаблоне. Добавьте в div-обёртку какой-нибудь дополнительный параметр. В результате он появится в обоих оборачивающих дивах?

Comment: да так и есть, я первым делом это проверил, думал мб где в шаблон обертка есть, но как меняю сразу вдвоем дублируются

Comment: Вместо проверки if($arResult){ попробуйте if(empty($arResult)){

Comment: То есть if(!empty($arResult)){ конечно же.

Comment: Извините оказывается js скрипт его двойным делал, убрал id все нормально стало, ну всеравно спасибо вам большое за помощь